# Haskell - converting High Order Function to recursive function

Tags: haskell, recursion

requirement:write function single - Tests whether exactly one element of a list satisfies a given condition.

```
single :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
```

I wrote this function:

```
single p xs = count p xs == 1
    where count pred  = length . filter pred
```

Question: What is the easy (correct) way to convert the above functions into one recursive function without using " High Order Functions"?

Comment: What is reason for this converting?

Answer (score 2):

You can do like that:

```
single p = lookupFirst
  where
    lookupFirst []                  = False
    lookupFirst (x:xs)  | p x       = lookupSecond xs
                        | otherwise = lookupFirst xs
    lookupSecond []                 = True
    lookupSecond (x:xs) | p x       = False
                        | otherwise = lookupSecond xs
```

Comment: I like that answer more than mine. The code is easier understood in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

We can use a `none` predicate that checks if the remainder of the list does not satisfy the condition:

```
single :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
single p []     = False
single p (x:xs) | p x       = none p xs
                | otherwise = single p xs

none :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
none _ [] = True
none p (x:xs) = not (p x) && none p xs
```

We thus also defined a `none` function that checks that no element in the given list satisfies a given predicate.

Or without passing the predicate through the recursion:

```
single :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
single p = helper
    where helper []     = False
          helper (x:xs) | p x = none xs
                        | otherwise = helper xs
          none []     = True
          none (x:xs) = not (p x) && none xs
```

The above written functions will also immediately stop from the moment a second item is found that satisfies the predicate. This can be useful if we work for instance with an *infinite* list. If there is a second item that satisfies the constraint, then the function will stop, if no such element or only one such element will ever be generated, we will however get stuck in an infinite loop (there is no much we can do about this). For example:

```
*Main> single even [1..] -- two or more elements satisfy the constraint
False
*Main> single even [1,3..] -- no element satisfies the constraint
^CInterrupted.
*Main> single even ([1,2]++[3,5..]) -- one element satisfies the constraint
^CInterrupted.
```

Answer (score 0):

**`xor` and `foldl`**

The most intuitive thing I can thing of is to just fold `xor` (exclusive or) and your function `f` thru the list. In case you're not familiar with the binary function `xor`, it returns `True` only when (at most) 1 of its arguments are `True`; otherwise `False`

```
xor :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
xor True  b = not b
xor False b = b

single :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
single f [] = False
single f xs = foldl (\acc -> xor acc . f) False xs

main = do
  putStrLn $ show (single even [])        -- False
  putStrLn $ show (single even [1])       -- False
  putStrLn $ show (single even [2])       -- True
  putStrLn $ show (single even [1,2])     -- True
  putStrLn $ show (single even [1,2,3])   -- True
  putStrLn $ show (single even [1,2,3,4]) -- False
```

---

**`Xor` monoid**

`xor` can be nicely encoded as a Monoid tho, which lends `single` to a more algebraic implementation using `foldMap`.

```
data Xor = Xor Bool

instance Monoid Xor where
  mempty                      = Xor False
  mappend (Xor True)  (Xor b) = Xor (not b)
  mappend (Xor False) (Xor b) = Xor b

single f xs = aux $ foldMap (Xor . f) xs
  where
    aux (Xor b) = b

main = do
  putStrLn $ show (single even [])        -- False
  putStrLn $ show (single even [1])       -- False
  putStrLn $ show (single even [2])       -- True
  putStrLn $ show (single even [1,2])     -- True
  putStrLn $ show (single even [1,2,3])   -- True
  putStrLn $ show (single even [1,2,3,4]) -- False
```

---

**auxiliary helper**

This is another way you can do it with an `auxiliary` helper. This one has an added benefit in that it exits immediately (stops iteration thru the list) after an answer is determined

```
single :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
single f xs = aux False f xs
  where
    aux b     f []     = b
    aux True  f (x:xs) = if (f x) then False else aux True f (xs)
    aux False f (x:xs) = aux (f x) f xs  

main = do
  putStrLn $ show (single even [])        -- False
  putStrLn $ show (single even [1])       -- False
  putStrLn $ show (single even [2])       -- True
  putStrLn $ show (single even [1,2])     -- True
  putStrLn $ show (single even [1,2,3])   -- True
  putStrLn $ show (single even [1,2,3,4]) -- False
```

---

**feedback welcome!**

I'm a Haskell newbie but maybe these ideas are interesting to you. Or maybe they're bad! Leave me a comment if there's anything I can do to improve the answer ^_^

Comment: So what's `single even [1,2,3,4,5,6]` in the first two versions?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov uff you totally schooled me – I overlooked that! I'm re-thinking the `xor` approach now. Any other input here?

Comment: Excellent explanations.
These kind of answers are more useful to me then ten articles.
I liked especially the answer with the helper function, because of its wide implication to other problems.